# Debug an installer project

Tags: c#, windows-installer

Could anyone tell me how to debug a custom installer class in an installer project.My custom installer class & the installer are present in same solution.

Regards,
Harsh Suman

Answer (score 4):

You can try inserting a Debugger.Break() inside the Installer class method you want to debug which will trigger a debugging session.

Or you could try attaching a debugger to msiexec.exe